# rxjava2 onNext is called for a disposed Observer

Tags: java, rx-java2

I have an `Observable` that downloads a series of items. It emits these items while downloading them.
What's happening is that even if I call dispose on the disposable the `onNext` is still called. I checked that the disposable has actually been disposed when the `onNext` is called.
It looks like this happens only if the downloading of the items is too quick for the Presenter to handle them. 
I could not find the documentation but it looks like if the `Observable` calls the `onNext` when the subscriber is still not disposed, then the item will be delivered even after the subscriber is disposed.

Is this true? If not, why is the `onNext` called when the disposable has already been disposed? Or in other words when would the `onNext` be called for a disposed Observer?

Does this mean that I have to check for the Observer not to be disposed before handling the `onNext`?

PS
I'm running the app on Android but I guess this is not relevant

Comment: Could you provide source code ?

Comment: Thank you @JEY. How would the source code help? Is it true that the Observer can be called or should this not happen? If it is not possible I will investigate the issue more before asking you to debug the app.

Comment: If you call dispose on Disposable you shouldn't receive any update from Observable. But you may have a race condition i don't know.

Comment: Ok I'll try to reproduce it with a smaller project and share it. thanks

Comment: You should provide the source code. You are doing something wrong.